# Copy Text to Clipboard Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I'm using [zeroClipboard.js](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) to be able to copy text to the clipboard.  I've researched here, and on other forums, but I don't know why I can't get it to work...

I downloaded the files and started up a localhost server, and nothing...

The Github repository, in my opinion, is overwhelmed with unnecessary files...

I read [this](http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard) article, copied the **EXACT** code, and got nothing.  Can someone tell my what's wrong? The invisible flash file isn't showing up.

```
//set path
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://davidwalsh.name/demo/ZeroClipboard.swf');
//create client
var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
//event
clip.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
});
clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
    alert('copied: ' + text);
});
//glue it to the button
clip.glue('copy');

// zeroClipboard.js is attached via EXTERNAL RESOURCES.
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqbk4/) is here, but probably not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have two problems:

1) Because of Flash Player security restrictions you should use `.swf` file from the same domain where your html files located. So the problem is in this line:

```
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://davidwalsh.name/demo/ZeroClipboard.swf');
```

To fix it you can change it to local path where your copy of `.swf` file is located:

```
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('ZeroClipboard.swf');
```

2) ZeroClipboard will work correctly only when running from server. Make sure that you're not running your web page from the local folder. (The URL in your browser's address bar must start with `http` not with `file:///`).

---

The library used in that article is outdated and has some bugs. I recommend you using newer version which is available here: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard